# window.location.href is not Refreshing/Reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

creating a refreshcart() function and in the function window.location.href is assigned to currentUrl. But while making an ajax call in the else block window.location.href = currentUrl, true; It doesn't refresh the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var productForm = $(".form-product-ajax")

  productForm.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log("Form is not sending!")
    var thisForm = $(this)
    //var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("action");
    var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("data-endpoint");
    var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
    var formData = thisForm.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      url: actionEndpoint,
      method: httpMethod,
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success: ", data)
        //currentPath = window.location.href --if cart is in current path--
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("cart") != -1) {
          refreshCart()
        }
      },
      error: function(errorData) {
        console.log("error: ", errorData)
      }
    })
  })

  function refreshCart() {
    console.log("In current cart")

    var currentUrl = window.location.href


    var refreshCartUrl = '/api/cart/'
    var refreshCartmethod = "GET";
    var data = {};

    $.ajax({
      url: refreshCartUrl,
      method: refreshCartmethod,
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success: ", data)
        console.log("If block starts")
        if ([data.products].length > 0) {
          console.log("Condition checked")
        } else {
          console.log("It came here")
          window.location.href = currentUrl, true;
        }
      },
      error: function(errorData) {
        console.log("Oh no! error: ", errorData)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Try `window.location.reload()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: Interesting that you want a page reload on `ajax`, defeats the purpose IMO. `location.reload()` should do it.

Comment: Thank you @Phil Cooper                          
location.reload() it reloads the whole page. Is there any other way to refresh a particular part of the page. Like here i just want my Cart table to be refreshed, not the coupon table or navbar or the footer.

Comment: Thank you @ambianBeing                            
location.reload() it reloads the whole page. Is there any other way to refresh a particular part of the page. Like here i just want my Cart table to be refreshed, not the coupon table or navbar or the footer.

Comment: @DebopriyoDas You need to recreate the cart information. There is no way to "reload" a part of a page like you are thinking.

Comment: @DaniloKörber Suppose there are two items in the cart. If I delete a item from the cart the item stays there but in the navbar the cart items count goes down to 1 from 2, but when I refresh/reload the page the items get removed from the cart. I just wanted to make it work like the navbar. Without reloading the entire page, just refreshing the cart table section where the items are displayed that i have added to the cart.

Comment: @DebopriyoDas it depends on how your cart is build. But this is another topic. You asked for help on reloading the page and this was already answered.

Comment: @DaniloKörber yeah you are right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `window.location.href = currentUrl, true;` is not valid. `window.location.href = currentUrl;` should work but is not recommended since you are using AJAX anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To relaod a page simply use

```
window.location.reload()
```